Why am i getting this syntax error: syntax error, unexpected 'private' (T_PRIVATE), expecting variable (T_VARIABLE)l
I'm a complete roockie at this, hoping you can help.
I get the syntax error when i pass the db.php.
{"exception":0,"message":"syntax error, unexpected 'private' (T_PRIVATE), expecting variable (T_VARIABLE)","file":"/###/db.php","line":8}
My code on that file is this:
class Database
{
    private ?PDO $conn = null;

    public function __construct(
        private string $host,
        private string $name,
        private string $user,
        private string $password
    ) {
    }

    public function getConnection(): ?PDO
    {


I have looked at the tutorial here on stackoverflow: Include, getting "PHP Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'private' (T_PRIVATE)"
But it's from 2016 and i didn't know if it's still current.
I think it makes sense that I'm passing private, public in one class, not good right?
Can anyone find an example of what i should be doing properly?
Remember, i'm a complete roockie, and any copy n' paste code examples would help me best...
Wishing you the best day.
Steve
I am trying to access my databaase through a JSON tutorial, but i am in the early phase and any JSON pass is not happening as atm i cannot even access my sample files, with the connection code, as it calls the syntax error.

In short, you need PHP 8.0.0 or later to run this code ~ https://3v4l.org/XsAoL

PHP/8 was released in November 2020 and its oldest branch is no longer supported. You should consider learning with an up-to-date version, ideally the latest.

If you're just starting with PHP you might not yet want to use Constructor Promotion. If you declare the private variable at the top of your class, and assign the argument of the constructor to it like this: $this->host = $host;, then your code will be easier to understand, and work with. It executes the same. I find the "Constructor Promotion" a bit of a questionable construct, and only if you use it consistently throughout your code base, and need often, it might be handy to have.

Thanks champions, sorry, the question looks duplicted, anyway, i think it should update to php 8.0, didn't know it's already four years now
